# different types in pandas column after read csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

I am reading in a .csv file, some entries of the columns are recognized as strings and some are recognized as float (Even though they are all having the same format!!!) I am using this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv( "data.csv", usecols = range(0,21), sep =';', decimal=',')
df[df.columns[0:21]] = df[df[0:21]].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Here the output of col1:

```
1               NaN
2               NaN
3               NaN
4               NaN
5               NaN 
...
164686       22.847412
164687       22.804832
164688       22.561518
```

After I tried to convert them, all the types which have been recognized as string are now of type "NaN". For me it seems like a python bug, since they are having exactly the same format. Here a few rows of the .vsc file

```
      Col1        Col1        Col3         
1     23,13854599;10,99679279;0;41,40728378;
2     23,24945831;10,96249676;0;41,54985428;
3     23,16853714;11,24223709;0;40,13756943;
4     23,0876255;10,66694546;0;40,24223328;
5     23,05908775;11,06436825;0;40,91619873;
...

164686  22,84741211;11,84464455;8,786539078;
164687  22,80483246;12,12989521;8,778803825;
164688  22,56151772;12,29102707;8,908541679;
```

Meanwhile I am really desperate! Important to know, I am limited to pandas 0.16.2, thus I cannot use e.g. methods like to_numeric.

Thank you very much for your help

EDIT:
Example for direct typecasting

```
df = pd.read_csv( "data.csv", sep =';',  usecols = range(0,21), dtype = {'Col1' : float, 'Col2' : float})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the column type while reading the CSV using the `dtype` argument:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: If I try to cast the types directly using dtype the following error occurs: ValueError: invalid literal for float()

Comment: Did you specify the `decimal` argument in this case? I don't see it in the edit above.

Comment: Sry I forgot it in my comment, but I used it. Still the same error.

Comment: You can try with `skipinitialspace=True` in your `pd.read_csv` call, to strip whitespace from values.